# Flutter: How to call a SnackBar form a class that is not a widget

Tags: http, flutter, interceptor, snackbar

I'm starting with flutter and I made a simple app that manages a Login screen using a REST API.

I'm using the http package and the [http_interceptor](https://pub.dev/packages/http_interceptor) package to intercept and send the token in the headers.

The problem is... I can catch the errors with the interceptor without any problem. But, there is any way to use a global snackbar that from my interceptor class can "notify" and redirect the user to the login screen showing any error in the app, when, for example, the token is invalid?

This is my Interceptor class:

```
class ApiInterceptor with ChangeNotifier implements InterceptorContract {
  final storage = new FlutterSecureStorage();
  @override
  Future<RequestData> interceptRequest({RequestData data}) async {
    [...] // here is the request interceptor
    return data;
  }

  // The response interceptor:
  @override
  Future<ResponseData> interceptResponse({ResponseData data}) async {
    final decodedResponse = json.decode(data.body);
    if (data.statusCode >= 400) {
      throw HttpException(decodedResponse['error']);
      // here i want to send the notification to a snackBar
      // then, i want to redirect the user to the login screen
    }
    return data;
  }
}
```

**[UPDATE I]**

Here is a provider that I use. In this provider I use the Interceptor.

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:cadsanjuan_movil/models/http_exception.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_secure_storage/flutter_secure_storage.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart';
import 'package:http_interceptor/http_interceptor.dart';
import '../config/http_interceptor.dart';
import '../config/.env.dart' as config;

class Auth with ChangeNotifier {
  String _endpoint = 'auth';

  final storage = new FlutterSecureStorage();
  // Http Interceptor
  Client http = HttpClientWithInterceptor.build(interceptors: [
    ApiInterceptor(),
  ]);

  Future singup(String email, String password) async {
    final url = "${config.apiBaseUrl}/$_endpoint/signin";
    try {
      final response = await http.post(url,
          body: json.encode({'email': email, 'password': password}));
      final decodedResponse = json.decode(response.body);
/*       if (response.statusCode >= 400) {
        throw HttpException(decodedResponse['error']);
      } */
      await storage.write(key: 'token', value: decodedResponse['token']);
      await storage.write(key: 'user', value: decodedResponse['user']);
      await storage.write(key: 'email', value: decodedResponse['email']);
      await storage.write(
          key: 'employeeId', value: decodedResponse['employeeId'].toString());
      //notifyListeners();
    } catch (error) {
      throw error;
    }
  }
}
```

And these providers are called on my main.dart with `MultipleProvider` widget:

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
          value: ApiInterceptor(),
        ),
        ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
          value: Auth(),
        ),
        ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
          value: TurnActive(),
        ),
      ],
      child: MaterialApp(
.
.
.
```

**[UPDATE II]**

Here is the `main.dart` updated... and stills not working.

```
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  final storage = new FlutterSecureStorage();
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'CAD App',
      theme: ThemeData(
        // This is the theme of your application.
        //
        // Try running your application with "flutter run". You'll see the
        // application has a blue toolbar. Then, without quitting the app, try
        // changing the primarySwatch below to Colors.green and then invoke
        // "hot reload" (press "r" in the console where you ran "flutter run",
        // or simply save your changes to "hot reload" in a Flutter IDE).
        // Notice that the counter didn't reset back to zero; the application
        // is not restarted.
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        body: MultiProvider(
          providers: [
            ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
              value: ApiInterceptor(context: context),
            ),
            ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
              value: Auth(context: context),
            ),
            ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
              value: TurnActive(context: context),
            ),
          ],
          child: FutureBuilder(
            future: storage.read(key: "token"),
            builder: (context, storedKey) {
              if (!storedKey.hasData) {
                return LoadingData(text: 'Por favor espere...');
              } else {
                return storedKey.data == null
                    ? LoginPage()
                    : InitialLoadingPage();
              }
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

On my interceptor:

```
.
.
.
@override
  Future<ResponseData> interceptResponse({ResponseData data}) async {
    final decodedResponse = json.decode(data.body);

    Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
      content: Text(decodedResponse['error']),
    ));
.
.
.
```

The error is:
`Scaffold.of() called with a context that does not contain a Scaffold.`

[image: error]

Comment: What about passsing the `Scaffold` `Context` through your class constructor?

Comment: How? The class doesn't called from any widget... can you explain me more please? Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Where is `ApiInterceptor` used in your code? There should be somewhere down your tree that you can pass `BuildContext` for this.

Comment: Ok the ApiInterceptor is called on some providers. I will update the question with a example...

Comment: Done @odonckers! Thanks for the help my friend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Updated answer

The original answer passes the `BuildContext` into your `ChangeNotifier` service which technically works, but after reviewing it I realized that it is quite unprofessional. This is because the whole concept of using a `Provider` or service is to separate the widget building and the background functions. Passing the `BuildContext` and creating a `Snackbar` from inside the service isn't really great. Bellow is a much more professional, slightly more work to wrap your head around it, but is much more flexible in the long run.

#### The idea

So that all the `Widget` code is contained inside of the class you are using for the UI and UX, you need to have some type of function that is in the class but only callable from your `ApiInterceptor`. To do this you are going to use what is called a [`typedef`](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#typedefs) that can be applied to a variable.

#### Step 1: Create the `typedef`

Your `typedef` should be created outside of the class, but still in the main file you're going to be applying it, preferably in the file containing `ApiInterceptor`.

```dart
typedef void OnInterceptError (String errorMessage);
```

If you've never worked with `typedef` in any language, you're probably extremely confused. All this is doing is creating a function type, that returns `void`, and takes a `String` for input.

#### Step 2: Using `OnInterceptError` inside `ApiInterceptor`

```dart
ApiInterceptor({
  @required this.interceptError,
}) : assert(interceptError != null);

final OnInterceptError this.interceptError;

// Response interceptor
@override
Future<ResponseData> interceptResponse({ResponseData data}) async {
  final decodedResponse = json.decode(data.body);
  if (data.statusCode >= 400) {
    throw HttpException(decodedResponse['error']);

    // Run `interceptError` to send the notification to a 
    // `Snackbar`
    interceptError(decodedResponse['error']);
  }
  return data;
}
```

After setting this up, you can finally get to the good part: setup the UI!!!

#### Step 3: Create the `OnInterceptError` function...

Now that you have where the function is run, you need to create where the function has its... **functionality**.

Wherever you implement this `ApiInterceptor` service, you now should pass something to the effect of the following.

```dart
ApiInterceptor(
  interceptError: (String errorMessage) {
    // Show the `Snackbar` from here, which should have
    // access to the `BuildContext` to do so and use
    // `interceptError` to create the message for the
    // `Snackbar`, if you'd like to do so.
    print(interceptError);
  }
);
```

At first it seems really really complicated, but it really is a nice way of doing things because it keeps your services and UI separated. Bellow is the original answer if you want a reference or still want to use that method.

## Original answer

Sadly because of how Dart works grabbing the `BuildContext` can be a little bit of a bear, but 100% possible. I'll walk you through the steps:

#### Step 1: Require `BuildContext` in `ApiInterceptor`

Currently your `ApiInterceptor` class is being declared without any input variables, so you'll add the following to your class at the top.

```dart
ApiInterceptor({
  @required this.context,
}) : assert(context != null);

final BuildContext context;
```

Now every time your class is accessed inside your code base you'll be notified by the IDE that there is a missing variable.

#### Step 2: Require `BuildContext` in `Auth`

You'll sadly have to do the exact same thing with your `Auth` provider. I'll spare you the same monologue as the last step since they're almost identical procedures. The following is what you must add to the beginning of the `Auth` class.

```dart
Auth({
  @required this.context,
}) : assert(context != null);

final BuildContext context;
```

Step 3: Pass `BuildContext` in every required case

You can probably figure this out, your IDE does most of the work for you! The following is the completed code for all your classes.

```dart
class ApiInterceptor with ChangeNotifier implements InterceptorContract {
  ApiInterceptor({
    @required this.context,
  }) : assert(context != null);

  final BuildContext context;
  final storage = new FlutterSecureStorage();

  @override
  Future<RequestData> interceptRequest({RequestData data}) async {
    [...] // here is the request interceptor
    return data;
  }

  // The response interceptor:
  @override
  Future<ResponseData> interceptResponse({ResponseData data}) async {
    final decodedResponse = json.decode(data.body);
    if (data.statusCode >= 400) {
      throw HttpException(decodedResponse['error']);
      // here i want to send the notification to a snackBar
      // then, i want to redirect the user to the login screen
    }
    return data;
  }
}

class Auth with ChangeNotifier {
  Auth({
    @required this.context,
  }) : assert(context != null);

  final BuildContext context;

  String _endpoint = 'auth';

  final storage = new FlutterSecureStorage();

  Future singup(String email, String password) async {
    // Http Interceptor
    Client http = HttpClientWithInterceptor.build(interceptors: [
      ApiInterceptor(context: context),
    ]);
    final url = "${config.apiBaseUrl}/$_endpoint/signin";
    try {
      final response = await http.post(url,
          body: json.encode({'email': email, 'password': password}));
      final decodedResponse = json.decode(response.body);
/*       if (response.statusCode >= 400) {
        throw HttpException(decodedResponse['error']);
      } */
      await storage.write(key: 'token', value: decodedResponse['token']);
      await storage.write(key: 'user', value: decodedResponse['user']);
      await storage.write(key: 'email', value: decodedResponse['email']);
      await storage.write(
          key: 'employeeId', value: decodedResponse['employeeId'].toString());
      //notifyListeners();
    } catch (error) {
      throw error;
    }
  }
}
```

And of course, your `main()` output:

```dart
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return MaterialApp(
    home: Scaffold(
      home: Builder(
        builder: (BuildContext context) => MultiProvider(
          providers: [
            ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
              value: ApiInterceptor(context: context),
            ),
            ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
              value: Auth(context: context),
            ),
            ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
              value: TurnActive(),
            ),
          ],
          child: /* CHILD!!! */,
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Make sure that the `Builder` is underneath the `Scaffold` in the tree, otherwise it won't recognize the `Scaffold` when calling `Scaffold.of(context)`.

I hope this helps and makes your day a *little* easier.

Comment: I have a problem trying to implement your code my friend.... When I try to pass context to `ApiInterceptor` there is an error on the IDE: "Only static members can be accessed in initializers." here: 
  Client http = HttpClientWithInterceptor.build(interceptors: [
    ApiInterceptor(context: context),
  ]);

Comment: I already fix the problem moving the client (`Client http = ...`) into the Future function. But when i try it, I have another error saying that can't find any scaffold to show the SnackBar... in the main.dart, in the child i have the Scaffold.

Comment: Oh... I forgot that your `BuildContext` must have an active `Scaffold` **before** you pass it. So I'd try moving your `MultiProvider` up the tree inside `MaterialApp`. If that doesn't work then try moving it a little farther inside the `Scaffold`, which is more likely to work.

Comment: Same error my friend. Please see my update II. Thanks for taking your time to help me! I really appreciate this.

Comment: I just updated the response, now it includes a `Builder` in the tree inside `Scaffold` and before your functions that require it for `Scaffold.of(context)`.

Comment: Ouch! Now I have a problem! Because the routes uses these Providers, now give me errors because the routes don't find the Providers in the widget tree. This haves sense because the routes property is on MaterialApp class and the Providers are now child of this class. Oh God.

Comment: I just updated my answer with a much better solution. After looking at your comment and then looking at my answer, I realized how unprofessional doing it the way I showed you would be. Technically it works, but isn't expandable and doesn't apply to the concept of UI in one class, services in another. Hopefully the answer above does the trick.

Comment: Thanks for your answer my friend. I have some questions about this solution. However, I think I have a problem anyway because 1) ApiInterceptor don't should be an Provider. 2) The provider must be at the top over MaterialApp, so I don't have at this level any Scaffold. Actually I'm catching the error of token expired on EVERY call to a future to the API. I know, this is a very BAD way, but I can't find another way to do it better =(